# How to draw circle/ellipse and square/rectangle with each other

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, shapes

What I want to do is that when I draw circle or ellipse in the picturebox, it will coexist when I draw rectangle or square. I tried many methods, but still, they won't. At first what I did is to create a shape list, but won't do the thing. and then I tried creating two lists for rectangle/square and circle/ellipse, but still won't create the result I wanted.Whenever I draw Circle after I draw a square/rectangle, the square/rectangle is erased; and vice versa.

---

Sample Screenshots:

[image: Square Drawing Screenshot]
[image: Circle Drawing Screenshot]

> I want it to be like this
>   [image]

Here's the code:

**Main**

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cbox_Grid.Checked =true;
    }
    Draw draw = new Draw();
    Shape s = new Shape();

    Shape.Buttons buttons = new Shape.Buttons();

    //X - Axis, Y - Axis, W = Width, H = Height
    int rX, rY, rW, rH;         //Rectangle Variables
    int sX, sY, sW, sH;         //Square Variables
    int cX, cY, cW, cH;         //Circle Variables
    int eX, eY, eW, eH;         //Ellipse Variables
    Color rC, sC, cC, eC, tC;     // Color Variables
    int tX, tY, tW, tH;         //Triangle Variables

    //Variables for Scaling
    int w1, h1, ave;
    int min_w, min_h, w_both, h_both;

    bool triangle;
    //Stroke Variables
    int strokeRect, strokeSquare,strokeCircle,strokeEllipse,strokeTriangle;


    #region Draw Button Event
    private void btn_Draw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (buttons)
        {
            case Shape.Buttons.rectangle:
                DrawRect();
                min_w = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
                min_h = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Height.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
                w_both = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text);
                h_both = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Height.Text);
                break;
            case Shape.Buttons.square:
                DrawSquare();
                min_w = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
                min_h = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
                w_both = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text);
                h_both = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text);
                trackBar_Size.Maximum = min_w + (128 - Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text));
                break;
            case Shape.Buttons.circle:
                DrawCircle();
                min_w = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
                min_h = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
                w_both = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text);
                h_both = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text);
                trackBar_Size.Maximum = min_w + (128 - Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text));
                break;
            case Shape.Buttons.ellipse:
                DrawEllipse();
                min_w = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
                min_h = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Height.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
                w_both = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text);
                h_both = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Height.Text);
                break;
            case Shape.Buttons.triangle:

                break;
        }

        pictureBox_Canvass.Paint += pictureBox_Canvass_Paint;
        pictureBox_Canvass.Refresh();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Rectangle PaintEvents
    public void DrawRect()
    {
        rX = (((486 / 2) - (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4)) / 2));
        rY = (((486 / 2) - (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Height.Text) * 96) / 25.4)) / 2));
        rW = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
        rH = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Height.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
        strokeRect = trackBar_Stroke.Value;
        rC = Color.Red;
    }
    public void AcceptRect()
    {
        Shape shape = new Shape();
        rC = Color.Gray;
        shape.strokeThickness = strokeRect;
        shape.points = new PointF(rX, rY);
        shape.width = rW;
        shape.height = rH;
        shape.color = rC;
        s._rectangles.Add(shape);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Square PaintEvents
    public void DrawSquare()
    {
        sX = (((486 / 2) - (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4)) / 2));
        sY = (((486 / 2) - (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4)) / 2));
        sW = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
        sH = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
        strokeSquare = trackBar_Stroke.Value;
        sC = Color.Red;
    }
    public void AcceptSquare()
    {
        Shape shape = new Shape();
        sC = Color.Gray;
        shape.strokeThickness = strokeSquare;
        shape.points = new PointF(sX, sY);
        shape.width = sW;
        shape.height = sH;
        shape.color = sC;
        s._rectangles.Add(shape);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Circle PaintEvents
    public void DrawCircle()
    {
        cX = (((486 / 2) - (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4)) / 2));
        cY = (((486 / 2) - (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4)) / 2));
        cW = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
        cH = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
        strokeCircle = trackBar_Stroke.Value;
        cC = Color.Red;
    }
    public void AcceptCircle()
    {
        Shape shape = new Shape();
        cC = Color.Gray;
        shape.strokeThickness = strokeSquare;
        shape.points = new PointF(cX, cY);
        shape.width = cW;
        shape.height = cH;
        shape.color = cC;
        s._circles.Add(shape);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Ellipse PaintEvents
    public void DrawEllipse()
    {
        eX = (((486 / 2) - (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4)) / 2));
        eY = (((486 / 2) - (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Height.Text) * 96) / 25.4)) / 2));
        eW = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
        eH = (Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Height.Text) * 96) / 25.4));
        strokeEllipse = trackBar_Stroke.Value;
        eC = Color.Red;
    }
    public void AcceptEllipse()
    {
        Shape shape = new Shape();
        eC = Color.Gray;
        shape.strokeThickness = strokeEllipse;
        shape.points = new PointF(eX, eY);
        shape.width = eW;
        shape.height = eH;
        shape.color = eC;
        s._circles.Add(shape);
    }
    #endregion

    public void DrawAllRect(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Shape shapes in s._rectangles)
        {
            switch (buttons)
            {
                case Shape.Buttons.rectangle:
                    s.DrawRectangle(shapes.color, shapes.strokeThickness, shapes.points, shapes.width, shapes.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.square:
                    s.DrawSquare(shapes.color, shapes.strokeThickness, shapes.points, shapes.width, shapes.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
    public void DrawAllCircle(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Shape shapes2 in s._circles)
        {
            switch (buttons)
            {
                case Shape.Buttons.circle:
                    s.DrawCircle(shapes2.color, shapes2.strokeThickness, shapes2.points, shapes2.width, shapes2.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.ellipse:
                    s.DrawEllipse(shapes2.color, shapes2.strokeThickness, shapes2.points, shapes2.width, shapes2.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.triangle:

                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    #region Accept-Reset-Cancel
    private void btn_Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (buttons)
        {
            case Shape.Buttons.rectangle:
                AcceptRect();
                break;
            case Shape.Buttons.square:
                AcceptSquare();
                break;
            case Shape.Buttons.circle:
                AcceptCircle();
                break;
            case Shape.Buttons.ellipse:
                AcceptEllipse();
                break;
            case Shape.Buttons.triangle:

                break;
        }
        pictureBox_Canvass.Paint +=pictureBox_Canvass_Paint;
        pictureBox_Canvass.Refresh();

        HideSettings();
        ShowButtons();

    }

    private void pictureBox_Canvass_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if(cbox_Grid.Checked)
        {
            draw.ShowGrid(sender, e);
            DrawAllRect(sender, e);
            DrawAllCircle(sender, e);
            switch (buttons)
            {
                case Shape.Buttons.rectangle:
                    s.DrawRectangle(rC, strokeRect, new PointF(rX, rY), rW, rH, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.square:
                    s.DrawSquare(sC, strokeSquare, new PointF(sX, sY), sW, sH, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.circle:
                    s.DrawCircle(cC, strokeCircle, new PointF(cX, cY), cW, cH, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.ellipse:
                    s.DrawEllipse(eC, strokeEllipse, new PointF(eX, eY), eW, eH, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.triangle:

                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            draw.ClearCanvass(sender, e);
            DrawAllRect(sender, e);
            DrawAllCircle(sender, e);
            switch (buttons)
            {
                case Shape.Buttons.rectangle:
                    s.DrawRectangle(rC, strokeRect, new PointF(rX, rY), rW, rH, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.square:
                    s.DrawSquare(sC, strokeSquare, new PointF(sX, sY), sW, sH, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.circle:
                    s.DrawCircle(cC, strokeCircle, new PointF(cX, cY), cW, cH, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.ellipse:
                    s.DrawEllipse(eC, strokeEllipse, new PointF(eX, eY), eW, eH, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.Buttons.triangle:

                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

}

**Shape Class**

```
public class Shape
{
    public Draw draw;
    public float width;
    public float height;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float x2;
    public float y2;
    public PointF points;
    public int strokeThickness;
    public Color color;
    public List<Shape> _rectangles = new List<Shape>();
    public List<Shape> _circles = new List<Shape>();
    public float acceptedStroke;
    public enum Buttons
    {
        rectangle, square, circle, ellipse, triangle
    }
    public void DrawRectangle(Color c, int stroke, PointF points, float w, float h,Graphics g)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;

        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(c,stroke), points.X, points.Y,w,h);
    }
    public void DrawSquare(Color c, int stroke, PointF points, float w, float h, Graphics g)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;

        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(c, stroke), points.X, points.Y, w, h);
    }
    public void DrawCircle(Color c, int stroke, PointF points, float w, float h, Graphics g)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;

        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(c, stroke), points.X, points.Y, w, h);
    }
    public void DrawEllipse(Color c, int stroke, PointF points, float w, float h, Graphics g)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;

        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(c, stroke), points.X, points.Y, w, h);
    }
}
```

Comment: please reduce the amount of code to the necessary bit, so that your problem becomes reproducible. 2 Shapes and the drawing code should suffice. There is no need for the code of switching on and off of buttons for example .

Comment: edited it @MongZhu. Is it fine now?

Comment: nope, still too much. Scenario: you want to draw 2 different shapes into a picture box. Leave only the code to make this scenario possible. Even the colours are not necessary.

Comment: edited again. @MongZhu. these are all essentials.

Comment: Why do you switch on `buttons`? It doesn't make sense. What is `buttons` supposed to be anyway? It seems to be an enum but you initialize it like a class? Again - makes no sense to me.

Comment: it is to determine what shape to draw, before all of this, the form shows 5 buttons for 5 shapes(square, rectangle, circle, ellipse and triangle) @Fildor

Comment: So if you *switch* on one of those types while drawing, how do you expect them to "co-exist" ?

Comment: Yes. Also thought of that. Already fixed the problem. Thank you for pointing that out atleast @Fildor

Comment: One thing you probably misunderstood is, that you call multiple times `pictureBox_Canvass.Paint += pictureBox_Canvass_Paint`. This attaches the same function multiple times to the same event. So move this line into the ctor after the `InitializeComponent()` call (or remove it entirely and add it through the designer).

Comment: Have you tried with a breakpoint at the "draw.ClearCanvass(sender, e);" line? This is called for every shape when the grid isn't checked.

Comment: @beyond thank you for the suggestion, but I already fixed the issue. God speed!